# Dampening meaning in: your output dampening is excellent?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/504966/adding-currrnet-limiting-capability-to-parraled-lm2596-ics) question and in the comment i have this texts:

> Also, unless your output dampening is excellent, it's usually a bad
>   idea to put unsychnronized SMPS in parallel, unless their datasheet
>   says that's possible. If you need more output current, get a larger
>   inductor, and a switcher IC that can handle more current or one that
>   supports an external MOSFET to handle the current. – Marcus Müller

So i want to know what is the meaning of **dampening** here :

**unless your output dampening is excellent**

Thanks.

Comment: In electronics the usual spelling is damping. It essentially means reducing oscillations. A dictionary would have shown you this if you'd had the right spelling.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about electronics, not English.

Comment: it done not meaning to be electronic phrase here and have indirect meaning here, i think maybe like some thing about good presentation and adding information to question!

Comment: Related https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67497/is-it-damping-or-dampening-when-referring-to-sound